# Duplicates in asp.net pagination when scraping?

Tags: asp.net, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this asp.net site and since request url is the same Scrapy dupefilter does not work. As a result I am getting tons of duplicated urls which puts my spider into infintite run. How can I deal with it?
[image]

My code looks as this.

```
if '1' in page:

            target =  response.xpath("//a[@class = 'dtgNormalPage']").extract()[1:]
            for i in target:
                i = i.split("'")[1]
                i = i.replace('$',':')
                yield  FormRequest.from_response(response,url,  callback = self.pages, dont_filter = True,
                formdata={'__EVENTTARGET':  i,

                            })
```

I tried to add a set to keep track of page numbers but have no clue how to deal with '...' which leads to the next 10 pages.

```
if '1' in page:

            target =  response.xpath("//a[@class = 'dtgNormalPage']")
            for i in target[1:]:
                page =  i.xpath("./text()").extract_first()
                if page in self.pages_seen:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.pages_seen.add(page)
                    i = i.xpath("./@href").extract_first()
                    i = i.split("'")[1]
                    i = i.replace('$',':')
                    yield  FormRequest.from_response(response,url,  callback = self.pages, dont_filter = True,
                    formdata={'__EVENTTARGET':  i,

                                }) 
              self.pages_seen.remove('[ ... ]')
```

The more threads I set the more duplicates I recieve.
So it looks like the only solution so far is to reduce thread_count to 3 or less.

Comment: I believe that collecting the urls here is not the best approach, more often than not the page url changes whenever you click for another page and if not, open the network tab, click a link, look at the request made and replicate it in scrapy. I'm happy to take a look at it if you provide a link

Comment: @Rafael Almeida Thanks for reply. I am not collecting the urls. I am collection the page numbers, that is the only unique identifier I can think of. Looks like it works so far.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain if I understad you correctly but asp.net usually relies a lot on cookies for delivering content. So when crawling asp.net websites you want to use cookiejar feature of scrapy:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'cookiejar_asp'

    def start_requests():
        for i, url in enumerate(start_urls):
            yield Request(url, meta={'cookiejar': i})

    def parse(self, response):
        # Keep in mind that the cookiejar meta key is not “sticky”. You need to keep passing it along on subsequent requests. For example:
        return Request(
            "http://www.example.com/otherpage",
            callback=self.parse_other_page
            meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},  # <--- carry over cookiejar
        )
```

Read more about cookiejars here:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cookiejar#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider

Comment: OP is asking how to prevent duplicate form posts when doing `FormRequest.from_response`